# Convert numbers in string to `_NUM-*_` symbol

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, numbers

Given a string with numbers:

```
I counted, ' 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 8 9 10 '
```

The goal is to convert the numbers to the `_NUM-*_` symbol where the `*` denotes the order by which the number occurs. E.g. given the above intpu the desired output is:

```
"I counted, ' _NUM-1_ _NUM-2_ _NUM-3_ _NUM-4_ _NUM-5_ _NUM-6_ _NUM-7_ _NUM-8_ _NUM-9_ _NUM-10_'"
```

Even if are repeated numbers, e.g. given the input

```
I said, ' 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 8 9 10 '
```

the desired output keeps the order of the number ignoring the value of the number itself e.g.:

```
"I said, ' _NUM-1_ _NUM-2_ _NUM-3_ _NUM-4_ _NUM-5_ _NUM-6_ _NUM-7_ _NUM-8_ _NUM-9_ _NUM-10_'"
```

I've tried:

```
import re

s = "I counted, ' 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 '"
num_regexp = '(?<!\S)(?=.)(0|([1-9](\d*|\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)))?(\.\d*[1-9])?(?!\S)'


re.sub(num_regexp, '_NUM_', s)
```

But it simply replaced the outputs with the same `_NUM_` symbol without keeping the order, i.e.

[out]:

```
"I counted, ' _NUM_ _NUM_ _NUM_ _NUM_ _NUM_ _NUM_ _NUM_ _NUM_ _NUM_ _NUM_ _NUM_ '"
```

I could do a post `re.sub` operation and replace each `_NUM_`, i.e.

```
import re

s = "I counted, ' 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 '"
num_regexp = '(?<!\S)(?=.)(0|([1-9](\d*|\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)))?(\.\d*[1-9])?(?!\S)'

num_counter = 1
tokens = []
for token in re.sub(num_regexp, '_NUM_', s).split():
    if token == '_NUM_':
        token = '_NUM-{}_'.format(num_counter)
        num_counter += 1

    tokens.append(token)

result = ' '.join(tokens)
```

[out]:

```
"I counted, ' _NUM-1_ _NUM-2_ _NUM-3_ _NUM-4_ _NUM-5_ _NUM-6_ _NUM-7_ _NUM-8_ _NUM-9_ _NUM-10_ '"
```

**Is a better way to achieve the desired output without first a generic `re.sub` and then a post-hoc string editing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) as a default argument to the function passed to `re.sub`.

```
>>> from itertools import count

>>> re.sub('(\d+)', lambda m, c=count(1): '_NUM_-{}'.format(next(c)), s)
' _NUM_-1 _NUM_-2 _NUM_-3 _NUM_-4 _NUM_-5 _NUM_-6 _NUM_-7 _NUM_-8 _NUM_-9 _NUM_-10 '
```

Note that I am using a simplified regex for matching number just to demonstrate how to get the count, you could replace it with regex that matches floats as well.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about `itertools.count` and using lambda inside the replacement is uber-cool!